# TabActivity OnTabChangedListener - how to get the previous selected tab

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a tab where when the user click on it i want a dialog to appear and keep him on the current tab (without switching to the selected tab).

I have the code of the dialog and the tab listener working but how do i keep the curren tab?

```
 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if(tabId.equals("SomeThing") && !(AppSettings.getIsFullVersion()))
            {
                callFullVersionDialog("Sorry, SomeThing is only available on full version");

            //  finish();
            }


        }});
```

Comment: do you mean if the user clicks on the selected tab, he stays on that tab?

Comment: If the user clicks on a speciffic tab he stays on its current tab (after a dialog is showing)

Comment: display in the fragment "not available in this version maybe with a link to full version"

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this,

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    // code to show your Dialog box here.

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position of your current tab here);

}
```

if each tab is a seperate fragment put your fragment position in there (0,1,2,3...).

Comment: I am using tabHost not fragments